# Load images from an array containing the filenames in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to load images from an array in jQuery?

```
The array looks like: var imgNames = ['images/image01.jpg, images/image02.jpg, images/image03.jpg']
```

And I want it to create the following inside a parent element:

```
<div id="imgNames">
  <img src="images/image01.jpg">
  <img src="images/image02.jpg">
  <img src="images/image03.jpg">
</div>
```

I've tried the following:

```
preload = function() {
    this.each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = imgNames;
    });
}
  var imgNames = ['images/image01.jpg, images/image02.jpg, images/image03.jpg'];
    $(document).ready(function(){
   // Preload Images:
preload();

});
```

which I found online, but I think it's tailored to replace existing elements - not creating them.

Comment: Your array `imgNames` only contains one singel item, you will have to enclose all the filenames with `'` like: `var imgNames = ['images/image01.jpg','images/image02.jpg','images/image03.jpg'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming an existing div:

```
<div id="imgNames"></div>
```

Then you can loop through the array as follows:

```
var imgNames = ['images/image01.jpg', 'images/image02.jpg', 'images/image03.jpg'];

$(document).ready(function() {
    var $div = $("#imgNames");

    $.each(imgNames, function(i, val) {
        $("<img />").attr("src", val).appendTo($div);
    });
});
```

Note: As per Krister's comment above, your array has one element that is a string containing all three image names. I've assumed you intended it to contain three strings each with one filename.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can

please see the code below

```
preload = function(images) {
    $(images).each(function() {
        $('<img/>').attr("src", this).appendTo("#imgNames");
    });
}
var imgNames = ['images/image01.jpg', 'images/image02.jpg', 'images/image03.jpg'];
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Preload Images:
    preload(imgNames);

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
preload=function(){   
$.each(imgNames,function(index,value){
$("#imgNames img:nth-child("index")").attr('src',value)
});
}
```